# Custom Fonts with SAPUI5 Theme Designer

Tags: css, sapui5

I have been developing a custom theme for using in HANA cloud platform Portal. I need to use custom fonts on my site, so I have deployed the fonts as an HTML application in HCP.

How can I use the fonts uploaded in this application in UI theme designer so that custom font-family is applied to all the apps using the custom theme?

I could not find a CSS parameter in the expert's tab related to fonts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to customise the font using the CSS tab, e.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might can load a custom font in the head of you index file, and then apply custom CSS to your project in order to have full control. You can load an additional custom CSS file from your index page, but I think you can also add it to your theme. I attached a code sample:

```css
* {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif !important;   
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and also load a custom CSS file which applies your font to you desired